# How to enter a comment

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Simple question, really.  I'm on an iPad and I don't see how to comment on (not answer) a question.

Comment: You need to crack the 50 rep mark unless it's on your own post or answers to your question